# How to divide number and string from string array?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

I have a question.

If I get `"10S2D*3T"` string, I have to divide number and not number like that.

What I want to do

**INPUT**

```
"10S2D*3T"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[10, 'S', 2, 'D','*',3,'T']
```

It's my result

```js
function solution(dartResult) {
    var answer = 0;
    var point = dartResult.split(/\D/gi);
    var option = dartResult.split(/\d/gi);
    console.log(point);
    console.log(option);
    return answer;
}

console.log(solution("10S2D*3T"));
```

Comment: Use the match method. Also your description is unclear since `D` and `*` are not numbers and are separated in the result.

Comment: What do you mean by "divide number" ? You want to extract the number from the input string ? You want to perform a division ? By the way, what is the meaning of "S", "D", "T" and "*" ? We need more context in order to provide accurate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string split method and pass it a regular expression to check for digits and filter the array of empty strings.

```
var regExp = /(\d*)/;
var output = '10S2D*3T'.split(regExp).filter(Boolean);

output will be:
["10", "S", "2", "D", "*", "3", "T"]
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAr3G.png

Comment: You should explain why you put the capture group in the regular expression. That's the important thing he was missing in his code.

Comment: capture group is for checking any number of digits in sequence.